# ObjectGraphBuilder from and to a file

Tags: groovy

How can I make ObjectGraphBuilder to build my class instance from an string? I mean if I have

```
String myString = """invoices{
    invoice(date: new Date(106,1,2)){

        item(count:5){
            product(name:'ULC', dollar:1499)
        }
        item(count:1){
            product(name:'Visual Editor', dollar:499)
        }
    }
    invoice(date: new Date(106,1,2)){
        item(count:4) {
            product(name:'Visual Editor', dollar:499)
        }
    }
"""
```

1. how can turn this string (myString) into an instance of the invoice class (I assume I have to use ObjectGraphBuilder but how?)
2. Given an instance of the class invoice ( with all of its nested properties), how can I turn that instance into an string like myString?

I also want to be able serialize and deserialize from a text file too but I assume it is the same as the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with GroovyShell to evaluate the string and delegate the methods called in the script to an ObjectGraphBuilder. I repeated the "invoices" method. If this is unacceptable, take a look at [Going to Mars with Domain-Specific Languages](http://www.slideshare.net/glaforge/going-to-mars-with-groovy-domainspecific-languages), by Guillaume Laforge, where he teaches how to customize the compiler.

I also created an `Invoices` class, because of the way ObjectGraphBuilder works. If this will be dynamic for you, take a look at its [resolvers](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/ObjectGraphBuilder.html).

```
import groovy.transform.ToString as TS
@TS class Invoices { List<Invoice> invoices=[] }
@TS class Invoice { List<Item> items=[]; Date date }
@TS class Item { Integer count; Product product }
@TS class Product { String name; Integer dollar; Vendor vendor }
@TS class Vendor { Integer id }

String myString = """
  invoices {
    invoice(date: new Date(106,1,2)){
      item(count:5){
          product(name:'ULC', dollar:1499)
      }
      item(count:1){
          product(name:'Visual Editor', dollar:499)
      }
    }
    invoice(date: new Date(106,1,2)){
      item(count:4) {
          product(name:'Visual Editor', dollar:499)
      }
    }
  }
"""

invoicesParser = { Closure c -> 
  new ObjectGraphBuilder().invoices c
}

binding = new Binding( [invoices: invoicesParser] )

invoices = new GroovyShell(binding).evaluate myString
assert invoices.invoices.size() == 2
```

---

**Update:** as for your second question, i'm not aware, and neither could found, any way back to the object graph builder representation. You can roll your own, but i think you will be better if you try something like json. Does your use case permit you to do so?

```
use( groovy.json.JsonOutput ) {
  assert invoices.toJson().prettyPrint() == """{
    "invoices": [
        {
            "date": "2006-02-02T02:00:00+0000",
            "items": [
                {
                    "product": {
                        "vendor": null,
                        "dollar": 1499,
                        "name": "ULC"
                    },
                    "count": 5
                },
                {
                    "product": {
                        "vendor": null,
                        "dollar": 499,
                        "name": "Visual Editor"
                    },
                    "count": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "date": "2006-02-02T02:00:00+0000",
            "items": [
                {
                    "product": {
                        "vendor": null,
                        "dollar": 499,
                        "name": "Visual Editor"
                    },
                    "count": 4
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}"""
}
```

Comment: Thanks but how do I convert an instance of the a map of the Invoice class (like the invoices in your code) to an string like the myString?